# How to implement my own language in Eclipse editor

Tags: sql, eclipse, programming-languages

I am working in a company which has a SQL like language .. where multiple sql statements 
can be bundled in procedures a la PL/SQL.

I want to add support for this language in Eclipse.  How do I go about this?  The compiler is already pre-built into the database hence there is no need to build a compiler.  I just need a few pointers on where and how to start.

Comment: Do you really want to implement a language, or do you just want to support syntax highlighting in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the [xtext project](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/), which looks quite nice for this purpose.

You could also try to modify [eclipse colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/) to do the job.

You can also take a look at this FAQ on the matter:

[The Official Eclipse FAQs: Implementing_Support_for_Your_Own_Language](http://wiki.eclipse.org/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs#Implementing_Support_for_Your_Own_Language)